# How to use "go get" correctly?

Tags: go

Now, I installed Go using `.msi` file.  I didn't any other setting.

```
> go env

set GO111MODULE=
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=      
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\herme\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOENV=C:\Users\herme\AppData\Roaming\go\env
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOINSECURE=
set GOMODCACHE=C:\Users\herme\go\pkg\mod
set GONOPROXY=
set GONOSUMDB=
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\herme\go
set GOPRIVATE=
set GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct
set GOROOT=C:\Program Files\Go
set GOSUMDB=sum.golang.org
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
PS C:\Users\herme\go\src\github.com\hermes7308\learngo> go env
set GO111MODULE=
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\herme\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOENV=C:\Users\herme\AppData\Roaming\go\env  
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOINSECURE=
set GOMODCACHE=C:\Users\herme\go\pkg\mod
set GONOPROXY=
set GONOSUMDB=
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\herme\go
set GOPRIVATE=
set GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct
set GOROOT=C:\Program Files\Go
set GOSUMDB=sum.golang.org
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GOVCS=
set GOVERSION=go1.16.4
set GCCGO=gccgo
set AR=ar
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set GOMOD=NUL
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\herme\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build2129994665=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

I can use the standard Go packages. For example, the below code has no problem.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello World!")
}
```

But, when I go get "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery" it results in the following:

```
> go get github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery

go: downloading github.com/andybalholm/cascadia v1.2.0
go: downloading golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20210510120150-4163338589ed

could not import github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery (cannot find package "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery" in any of 
    C:\Program Files\Go\src\github.com\PuerkitoBio\goquery (from $GOROOT)
    C\src\github.com\PuerkitoBio\goquery (from $GOPATH)
    \Users\herme\go\src\github.com\PuerkitoBio\goquery (from $GOPATH))compilerBrokenImport
```

And pkg is created,

[image]

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/#getting-started . And stick to it. No being clever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run

```
go mod init ANYNAME
```

in the workspace folder

and run

```
go mod tidy
```

Comment: This is wrong. You're making assumptions. Don't.